# passing array of string from php to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-post

I want to tranform a php array of string into html. My php and html code are in the same page.

I have `$myvar` that hold my array of string. I pass `$myvar` with `POST` and insert it to `$ba`.

My code needs to print on html page 3 line (in while loop).
But when I pass the `$be`, it writes me error message: "Notice: Undefined index: myvar" (in php code)

What do I need to repair so that my code prints to my screen all the 3 lines that I get from php?

my code:(php)

```
foreach ($docres as $key=>$filename) {
    $counter = 0; 
    $file = $filename +1;
    $handle = fopen($dir."/".$file.'.txt',"r");
    if($handle)
    {
        while($counter < 3)
        {
            $myvar[]=fgets($handle);
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

$ba = implode("
", $myvar);

my html code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <center> 
        <h1> My Search Engine </h1>
        <input type = 'text' size='90'  value='' name = 'search' > <br> 
        <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Search source code'>         
    </center> 
</form >
<p> <?php echo $ba ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply echo the mysql query on a function and call it on HTML as follows:
**UPDATE:** 3rd column will be an image wich route are stored on database, and 4th col will be an image eich only the name was stored on database (because we know the full route) as example:

```
 <?php
    function printOnHtml(){
    include ("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM foo;"
    if ($result = connection()->query($sql)){
        $rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        while ($rs[0] != ''){
           echo "first column: ".$rs[0]." second column: ".$rs[1]." image with full route on database: <img src='".$rs[2]."' alt=''> <br> if only the img name is stored cuz we know the route: <img src='img_route/".$rs[3]."' alt=''>";
           $rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        }
    }
    }
```

Then on HTML

```
<html>
blablabla
<body>
blablabla
<?php
    printOnHtml();
?>
blablabla
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it have to be a .php file to call the php function (for example index.php)

I paste the connection php script i use in order if you need it:

```
<?php
function connection(){
if($mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost","user","password","database_name")) echo "OK"; else echo "KO";
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

i did it with mysqli fetch array, but you can do the same using fetch assoc if you want.

**UPDATE2:** If you stubborness makes you follow using a txt to store data (wich, if increase will fail when you get a some thousands line txt), modify this on your code:

```
$myvar='';
foreach ($docres as $key=>$filename) {
    $counter = 0; 
    $file = $filename +1;
    $handle = fopen($dir."/".$file.'.txt',"r");
    if($handle)
    {
        while($counter < 3)
        {
          if(isset($myvar)){
            $myvar=fgets($handle);
         }
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

and i'm supposing that you declared $dir, $file and other vars properly.
You NEVER have to use vars without declaring it (as NULL at least). You only can do this if you ensured 100% that this var will get a value at this point.

Comment: oh and...  undefined index means just this, you didn't defined the index before using so, if null or wrong, you get this error. Must define it at the top as $myVar = "";

Then you use it after when you need it.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
my function is not a sql - the files are saved in my storage folder becuse I'm trying to write an inverted index search programe, so in my sql I have word that point to a file.
So I got the file I need to print out, and I want to print the first three rows.. how do I do that?

Comment: to print a file which route is stored in database? let me edit the example and see by yourself

Comment: Oh and.. you don't need javascripts to reach this job, it's lighting faster using php, specially when dealing with images. =)

Comment: lool I did update to the code but its still not working

Comment: you need to use database man.... you're trying to do the most insecure hole in the world saving data on a txt, and you'll get a slowly, insecure and many other wrong adjectives web application, and you'll get a headache (or a pair) trying to re-invent the wheel (this .txt data storing was used 20years ago). Anyway if you want to continue as is, define to blank the vars that gets you an error of undefined index (add $myVar = ""; at the begining of the page)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the array to string in a correct way using implode and `<br>` as a separator
Then just print it using php tags (as you are using both at the same page ) you can access the variable direct and print it using `<?= $ba ?>` or `<?php echo $ba ; ?>`

Code will be :

```
<?php
foreach ($docres as $key=>$filename) {
$counter = 0; 
    $file = $filename +1;
    $handle = fopen($dir."/".$file.'.txt',"r");
    if($handle)
    {
        while($counter < 3)
        {
            $myvar[]=fgets($handle);
            $counter++;
        }
    }
}
$ba = implode("<br>", $myvar);
?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <center> 
        <h1> My Search Engine </h1>
        <input type = 'text' size='90'  value='' name = 'search' > <br> 
        <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Search source code'>         
      </center> 
</form >
<p id="deatiles"> <?= $ba ?> </p>
```

Comment: @adi are you sure there is a data in $myvar ?
please try print_r($myvar); and check if there is a data

Comment: and please make sure to remove the js code as it is not correct and the $ba at it will be undefined

Comment: yes I check it and there is a data. $myvar hold array of string like this: "Array ( [0] => All Of Me ) Array ( [0] => All Of Me [1] => JOHN LEGEND ) "

Comment: now its print to my sreen :" <= $ba ?>" and not my data

Comment: yes sorry i edited the answer from 5 min , it is <?= $ba ?> not <= $ba ?> 
or you can use <?php echo $ba ?>

Comment: no the same error :" Undefined variable: ba " after I change the code to : <?= $ba ?>

Comment: 1- are you sure you updated the php code ? to remove $ba. from the loop and add $ba = implode("<br>", $myvar); outside the loop ? ,2 - are you sure both the php and html is included at the same page ?